# Brother 4150 CDN "Deep Sleep" How do I disable?

Tags: printer

We own a Brother 4150 CDN printer which has a "deep sleep" feature that makes the printer stop working until someone pushes a button. The maximum wait before deep sleep is 210 minutes.

Is there a way to disable it?

Answer (score 10):

To cancel DEEP SLEEP on Brother Printer

1. Go to General Setup then OK
2. Ecology then OK
3. SLEEP TIME then OK
4. While sleep time is display push Down Arrow and CANCEL at the same time!
5. DEEP SLEEP on/off toggle by Arrow keys
6. OK to SAVE Deep Sleep off.

Comment: Can you also adjust the deep sleep time?

Comment: For HL2360D, press [Down Arrow] and [BACK].

Answer (score 3):

I tried to just comment on tony Benjamin's answer, but apparantly I can't do that without 50 reputation.  I was having the same problem, but with a Brother HL-2280DW and I fixed it (or at least got to the right menu item) by ALMOST following tony Benjamin's steps in the control menu in the printer itself.  Specifically what I did was:

1. Go to General Setup then OK
2. Ecology then OK
3. Sleep Time then OK
4. While sleep time is displayed push Job Cancel and Start at the same time!
5. Deep Sleep on/off toggle by arrow keys.
6. OK to save Deep Sleep off.

Note that the only difference is that instead of using the down arrow and Cancel at the same time I used Start and Job Cancel.

Comment: Thanks, this also worked for the Brother MFC-7360 printer.

Answer (score 2):

[You can change the timeout setting here](http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/BSC/public/us/us/en/faq/faq/000000/000100/000010/faq000110_016.html?reg=us&c=us&lang=en&prod=hl4150cdn_all&Cat=102), however, there does not seem to be a option to disable.

The wakeup should be triggered by print activity. How are you printing to the device? Which client OS? Which TCP ports? I've seen suggestions that moving to [RAW 9100 printing versus LPR-style](http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/BSC/public/us/us/en/faq/faq/000000/002500/000086/faq002586_000.html?reg=us&c=us&lang=en&prod=hl2270dw_all&Cat=112) printing can help this.

I have similar printers in a Linux environment, but they're configured as port 9100 JetDirect printers, so the devices wake when jobs are submitted.

Comment: Thanks.  We found that print activity doesn't work.  Almost all clients are Win 7 Pro sharing the printer from a Win 2008 server using bog standard printer shares.  I'll look into 9100 as it may solve our problems.  Thanks.

Comment: You can easily reconfigure the TCP Printer port in W2K8 to switch between LPR and JetDirect (port 9100). I have some Lexmarks with similar issues. They stay awake if you use JetDirect and go to sleep on LPR.

Comment: @CodeSilverback Did it work for you?